# Nested Scrollview not working inside MapMarker's Bubble

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, mousewheel, non-scrolling

In my current layout, scrollview is not detecting the mouse's scroll-wheel scrolling in either direction to navigate it's text upwards or downwards. You are able to click and drag with either mouse button or click and drag with the mouse's scroll-wheel.

Click prints:

```
MyMap Down
MyBubble Down
MyBox Down
MyBoxes_Box Down
MyBoxes_Box2 Down
MyScroll2 Down
MyGrid2 Down
MyLabel2 Down
```

Click and Drag prints:

```
MyMap Down
MyBubble Down
MyBox Down
MyBoxes_Box Down
MyBoxes_Box2 Down
MyScroll2 Down
```

If you only use the mouse wheel in scrollview above the mapview, prints:

```
MyMap Down
<kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x000002A4C1302458>
```

Layering of Kivy App, shows RelativeLayout:

```
MyMap Down
<kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x000001E26AA42458>
MyBubble Down
<kivy.uix.relativelayout.RelativeLayout object at 0x000001E278CE2458>
MyBox Down
<kivy.uix.bubble.BubbleContent object at 0x000001E278D51C10>
MyBoxes_Box Down
<__main__.MyBox object at 0x000001E278D51C78>
MyBoxes_Box1 Down
<__main__.MyBoxes_Box object at 0x000001E278D51CE0>
MyScroll1 Down
<__main__.MyBoxes_Box1 object at 0x000001E278D51D48>
MyGrid1 Down
<__main__.MyScroll1 object at 0x000001E278D51E18>
MyLabel1 Down
<__main__.MyGrid1 object at 0x000001E278D8B1E8>
```

I have added an `on_touch_down` event to help show that kivy is detecting the touch inside the scrollview widget but also detecting all parent widgets as well, I think it has something to do with the `RelativeLayout` but I've tried a bunch of stuff in the documentation and am stuck. If you plug and play my example, you can click the scrollview/label and then click and drag the scrollview/label to see the different events occuring based on mouse/click behavior. I have also added a `walk()` command to show that once the bubble is added, a `RelativeLayout` is created for all it's children widgets which I believe is where the `touch.is_mouse_scrolling= 'scrollup'/'scrolldown'` motion event is being absorbed by the `MapView`.

If anyone can help me solve this issue I would greatly appreciate it!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView, MapLayer, MapMarkerPopup, MarkerMapLayer
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
class MyScroll1(ScrollView):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyScroll1 Down')
            print (self.parent)
        return super(MyScroll1, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyScroll2(ScrollView):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyScroll2 Down')
        return super(MyScroll2, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyMarker(MapMarkerPopup):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyMarker Down\n')
        return super(MyMarker, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyMap(MapView):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyMap Down')
            print (self.parent)
        return super(MyMap, self).on_touch_down(touch)

class MyBubble(Bubble):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyBubble Down')
            print (self.parent)
        return super(MyBubble, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyBox Down')
            print (self.parent)
        return super(MyBox, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyBoxes_Box(BoxLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyBoxes_Box Down')
            print (self.parent)
        return super(MyBoxes_Box, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyBoxes_Box1(BoxLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyBoxes_Box1 Down')
            print (self.parent)
        return super(MyBoxes_Box1, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyBoxes_Box2(BoxLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyBoxes_Box2 Down')
        return super(MyBoxes_Box2, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyBtn_Box(BoxLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyBtn_Box Down')
        return super(MyBtn_Box, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyGrid1(GridLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyGrid1 Down')
            print (self.parent)
        return super(MyGrid1, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyGrid2(GridLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyGrid2 Down')
        return super(MyGrid2, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyLabel1(Label):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyLabel1 Down')
            print (self.parent, '\n')
        return super(MyLabel1, self).on_touch_down(touch)
class MyLabel2(Label):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            print ('MyLabel2 Down\n')
        return super(MyLabel2, self).on_touch_down(touch)

class TestMapView(App):
    def build(self):
        lat = 30.6394
        lon = -100.057
        newMap = MyMap(zoom=5, lat=lat, lon=lon)
        newMap.map_source = 'osm'
        newMap.map_source.min_zoom = 2
        text1 = 'A bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\nA bunch of text1\n'
        text2 = 'A bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\nA bunch of text2\n'
        marker = MyMarker(id='marker', lat=lat,lon=lon, color= (128,0,0,1), popup_size= (1200,700))
        bubble = MyBubble(id='bubble')
        box = MyBox(id='box', orientation="vertical", padding="5dp", size_hint=(1,1))
        boxes_box = MyBoxes_Box(id='boxes_box', orientation="horizontal", size_hint=(1,.95))
        boxes_box1 = MyBoxes_Box1(id='boxes_box1', orientation="vertical", size_hint=(.5,1))
        boxes_box2 = MyBoxes_Box2(id='boxes_box2', orientation="vertical", size_hint=(.5,1))
        scroll_box1 = MyScroll1(size_hint=(1,.8))
        scroll_box2 = MyScroll2(size_hint=(1,.8))
        grid1 = MyGrid1(size_hint=(1,None), height=900, cols=1)
        grid2 = MyGrid2(size_hint=(1,None), height=900, cols=1)
        boxes_btn_box = MyBtn_Box(id='boxes_btn_box', orientation="horizontal", padding="5dp", size_hint=(1,.05))
        backs = Button(id='backs', text='Back', size_hint=(.4,1))
        nexts = Button(id='nexts', text='Next', size_hint=(.4,1))
        label1 = MyLabel1(id='l1', text="{}".format(text1), font_size=20, markup=True, halign="left")
        label2 = MyLabel2(id='l2', text="{}".format(text2), font_size=20, markup=True, halign="left")

                                            #MapMarkerPopup
        marker.add_widget(bubble)               #Bubble
        bubble.add_widget(box)                      #Box
        box.add_widget(boxes_box)                       #Boxes_Box
        boxes_box.add_widget(boxes_box1)                    #Boxes_Box1
        boxes_box1.add_widget(scroll_box1)                      #Scroll1
        scroll_box1.add_widget(grid1)                               #Grid1
        grid1.add_widget(label1)                                        #Label1
        boxes_box.add_widget(boxes_box2)                    #Boxes_Box2
        boxes_box2.add_widget(scroll_box2)                      #Scroll2
        scroll_box2.add_widget(grid2)                               #Grid2
        grid2.add_widget(label2)                                        #Label2
        box.add_widget(boxes_btn_box)                   #Button-Box
        boxes_btn_box.add_widget(backs)                     #Button
        boxes_btn_box.add_widget(nexts)                     #Button
        newMap.add_widget(marker)
        tree = [type(widget) for widget in bubble.walk()]
        print('\n', tree, '\n')
        return newMap

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestMapView().run()
```